# Traffic Ticket in Germany

Tags: tickets, traffic

Today a letter have appeared in my mailbox in the USA. From what I understand, it is a traffic ticket, from Germany. I just want to know if traffic tickets can be enforced to US Authorities.

Comment: @GregHewgill I think we can assume it is.  If he's asking how to avoid paying (ie can he just not pay it) we don't support those law-avoidances here, so let's presume the best and mark as duplicate, unless OP disagrees.

Comment: good luck when/if police will stop you next time you will visit Germany

Answer (score 2):

It is very unlikly that either from the German side (making a request) or the US side (complying the request) that anybody will undertake anything.

As the quote below states, Germany will not enforce US fines.
That would emply that there is no agreement between the two countries in this matter (as there are within the EU).

It is probably considered a too costly affair.

Unless you are caught again by the same state commiting a further traffic offence (where they would then see that there is something open), nothing is likly to happen upon return.

---

> **Was droht, wenn ich Forderungen aus den USA nicht bezahle?**
>
> > Bußgelder aus den USA lassen sich in Deutschland **nicht vollstrecken**, allerdings müssen Verkehrssünder ggf. mit Problemen bei der Ein- bzw. Ausreise rechnen.
>
> **What if I don't pay claims from the United States?**
>
> > Fines from the USA **cannot be enforced** in Germany, but traffic offenders may face problems when entering or leaving the country.

---

**Sources**:

- [Bußgeldkatalog USA - Verkehrsregeln & Bußgelder im Ausland 2020](https://www.bussgeldkatalog.org/usa/)

Comment: Your quote is about the reverse direction, traffic offenses in the US being served to someone in Germany. The OP is asking about a ticket from Germany being sent to the US. I agree that it will not be enforced but depending on how big the fine is he might have issues traveling back to Germany or if it crosses some threshold even the EU.

Comment: @moggi The quote was stated as such. The reason for that also explained. Remeber also for a € 15 fine, they will not start a proces that may cost hundreds to (possibly) collect.  The way data is stored, such fines (which are state or city fines) will not be centrally collected. This may change in 2021 with the introduction of ETIAS/EES and the corresponding services. Then when leaving, Border Control could see that a specific person has collected a amount of fines around Europe during their visit.